# Grouping by CET Time in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to aggregate data in mongodb, to group by user and CET time my document. According to the documentation, i tried the following :

```
    db.WORKING_HOURS.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { user : "$user", date : { $add: [ "$heure", 60*60000 ] }},
           nombre: { $sum : 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

My data have these forms :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b0b2bf32d3cd188cea9e1a"),
    "user" : 1,
    "heure" : ISODate("2017-02-24T22:25:03.180Z")
}
```

I'm not able to correctly aggregate my data. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your answer.

You haven't taken day light savings into account
as CET uses UTC+1 (standard time) and UTC+2 (daylight saving time).

`$dayOfYear` will group the same day values across years.

You can try below things.

You can group dates in server time and convert to CET timezone before presenting it to user.

Other alternative would be add offset when adding date in the database.

Something like this.

```
{
    "date": ISODate("2017-02-24T00:00:00Z"),
    "offsetmillis": 3600000
} 
{
    "date": ISODate("2017-03-27T00:00:00Z"),
    "offsetmillis": 7200000
}
```

You can use the below aggregation to group by date.

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      date: {$dayOfMonth: {$add: ["$date", "$offsetmillis"]}},
      month: {$month: {$add: ["$date", "$offsetmillis"]}},
      year: {$year: {$add: ["$date", "$offsetmillis"]}}
    },
      count: {$sum: 1}
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, i think you solution is better than mine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i tried to group by date, but time is constantly changing, so normally, it's not possible to groups my values, and it explain why i add multiple group.

To fix this, i use the $dayOfWeek operator (from date)

Result :

```
[
  {
    $group : {
       _id : {user : "$user", jour : {$dayOfYear : { $add: [ "$heure", 1000*60*60 ] }}},
       nombre: { $sum : 1 }
    }
  }
```

]